# Opencv undistortPoints Assertion failed

Tags: c++, opencv

I am triyng to undistort an image with opencv undistortPoints function. I get the following assertion.

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.isContinuous() && (src.depth() == CV_32F     || src.depth() == CV_64F) && ((src.rows == 1 && src.channels() == 2) || src.cols*src.channels() == 2)) in cv::undistortPoints, file D:\OpenCV\2.4.11\opencv\sources\modules\imgproc\src\undistort.cpp, line 394

I can't firgure out why I get this assertion. Here is the code:

```
    cv::Mat pixel_locations_src = cv::Mat(src.size(), CV_32FC2);

    for (int i = 0; i < src.size().height; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < src.size().width; j++) 
        {
            pixel_locations_src.at<cv::Point2f>(i,j) = cv::Point2f(j,i);
        }
    }

    cv::Mat pixel_locations_dst = cv::Mat(src.size(), CV_32FC2);

    std::cout<<cameraMatrix<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<distCoeffs<<std::endl;

    cv::undistortPoints(pixel_locations_src, pixel_locations_dst, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs);
```

This is what the input arguments look like:

pixel_locations_src is a 1920x1080 matrix.
cameraMatrix is 3x3.
distCoeffs is 8x1.

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPOWR.png)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you passed a 1920x1080 matrix as the source, I suspect the assertion is on `src.rows == 1`. It should be straightforward to debug this at the point it asserts.

Comment: Yes. I changed  `cv::Mat pixel_locations_src = cv::Mat(src.size(), CV_32FC2);` to `cv::Mat pixel_locations_src = cv::Mat(src.rows*src.cols, 1, CV_32FC2);` and it works.